# I need advice on where to move some questions of mine

Tags: support, migration, unanswered-questions

There are some questions of mine that have received few attention and I'm considering to migrate them to another site (if it's possible to do so), where maybe they are more pertaining and more on-topic.
The questions are the following:

https://superuser.com/questions/585295/how-to-customize-logout-options-under-linux

https://superuser.com/questions/584446/how-to-properly-configure-grub-settings-from-kde-system-settings

https://superuser.com/questions/586031/quick-usb-pendrive-formatting-under-kde

https://superuser.com/questions/584896/repository-to-upgrade-sigil-to-latest-version-on-kubuntu

As you can see they are all linux questions, and my thought was to try to migrate them on "Unix and Linux" or "Ask Ubuntu", but I don't know:

1. If this is an accepted behaviour; the site rules allow me to do that?
2. Where should I move them if I'm allowed to do so; I don't know well the communities behind these sites, so I'm uncertain about where should I look.

Comment: Seems like you'd have better luck at Ask Ubuntu? I'm not terribly familiar with the site so someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to move a question (and if you're doing so voluntarily - don't let anyone coerce you into moving your question if it's on-topic here), you can flag it for moderator attention and let us know which site you'd like it moved to. Moderators have the ability to migrate any question to any site (unless the question is more than 60 days old or if you're question-banned on the destination site, but neither seems to apply in this case).

It's perfectly acceptable to ask to have your question moved if you later decide it would be a better fit elsewhere. Just *make sure* that the question will be a good fit on the destination site, and you may need to edit it to better fit the destination site's community. A good way to check this is to read the site's FAQ and ask some regular user in that site's chat room.

Comment: Yes, nobody tried to force me to move them, it is just that they haven't had enough attention so I'm trying to have them answered somewhere else. Do you think that these questions will have more success on Unix and Linux or AskUbuntu?